# Shifting Bounds of an excel array by an arbitrary number of columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change the left bound of an array by an arbitrary amount of columns.  for example i have the range A4:AA4.  I want to shift the left bound of the array to D4:AA4.  The number of columns that i shift the array by is arbitrary.  So it could be  D4:AA4, E4:AA4, F4:AA4 ...etc

I want to be able to do this in a formula, not through VBA.  I want to use this range INSIDE a =MATCH() function.  Could anyone help me out with this? thanks!

Comment: sounds like you want the 'Offset' spreadsheet function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish here. Are you just looking for an absolute cell reference in your formulas? In case you are consider the following:

```
A   B   C
2   5   3
3   6   
4   7   
5   8   
6   9   
7   10  
8   11  
9   12
```

Column A contains the numbers  1 - 9
In B1 i type in the following formula `=SUM(A1+$C$1)` which i then autofilled until B8.

The dollar sign makes the both the column and row reference absolute and will not shift as part of the autofill.

If this is way of the mark so you have another way of explaining it or maybe included some sample data and desired output.